# Can supervisord's `supervisor stop` be compared to a keyboard interrupt?

Tags: python, supervisord

I have a python script and the script is run in background as a supervisor job.

If I were to give the command:

`$ sudo supervisorctl stop myscript`

What's going on behind the scenes?

If I had not handled the exception, will this be considered a graceful shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

While your question is not fully complete-

at its most basic, *not exactly*. If you mean how Python handles the `Exception`, it really depends on how you are calling the command and handling any codes or errors from it. All python Exceptions should inherit from [BaseException](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), but you shouldn't catch that normally and instead catch `Exception` or some form of `subprocess.SubprocessError` (which inherits from Exception).

However, if you mean how `supervisorctl` handles this internally, it probably has similar logic to what you are expecting: sending an exit signal for the process to handle. As you seem most familiar with Python, the [signal library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) may be insightful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ti7. I have handled exception in my script and have mentioned to print the output to a file, if at all I hit one. My assumption was that if i stop the supervisor job, it's more of an interruption, right? Contradicting my expectation, the script gracefully exited, and no file was created.

Comment: It is being "interrupted", but in a way that alerts the program "it's time to exit". I suspect that it may simply be sending [`SIGTERM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGTERM) (instruct the program to exit), while you are thinking it would send [`SIGKILL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGKILL) (immediately end/remove the resources)

Comment: is there by anyway, I could handle the exits due to sigterm?